# Windows Media Video (WMV) Specification and Resources

Tags: video, wmv, codec

I would like to write my own cross-platform library (codec etc..) for Windows Media Video format, so I'm looking for a specification and other papers about this video format, but I didn't found any so I'm asking you if you know about any good resources...

Note: I found the ASF specs.

Answer (score -1):

As I know, there is no public official specifications of WMV codecs. You can try to view open sources from third party implementations (for example ffmpeg, VLC). In addition, there are number of codecs from WMV family, and for some of the codecs (e.g. WMV 9 Screen) I doubt, that a third party implementation exists at all.

Answer (score -1):

File format of WMV is same as ASF, download ASF viewer(https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=12826) which is a Microsoft tool to view the file structure of ASF and WMV, where you can see both formats are same.

Answer (score -1):

ASF File Format is developed by Microsoft Corporation.

- **ASF File Format Overview:** [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmformat/overview-of-the-asf-format)
- **Specification:** [ASF_Specification.doc](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/0/790fecaa-f64a-4a5e-a430-0bccdab3f1b4/ASF_Specification.doc)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).